# Report takes almost 25 minutes or over (Jasper)

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jasper-reports, heap-memory

I have so much data to be shown off. For large data (it's about more than 500.000 records) which has 30.000 pages to be displayed, it needs 25 minutes or over while i have increased both Java Virtual Machine and Java Heap. The increasing memory of each is 4GB for 64-bit. I also change the setting of iReport so that has ignore pagination mode. Could anyone tell me what kind of the problem is it? Thanks

Comment: can you profile it, is it fetching data consuming time or generating report ?

Comment: I think both of them. Because when i load that query, it takes for over 2 minutes. But when i run generating report it takes 1513 seconds or over 25 minutes. So, do you have any suggestion?